# C++ stoi throws out_of_range while converting int

Tags: c++

I am parsing a CSV file like this:

```
while (std::getline(iss, value, ',')) {
            cout << col << " " << value << endl;
            switch (col) {
                case 0: customer.id = std::stoi(value); break;
```

And it stops at the very first value.
In my console I have this:

```
0 3222947947
```

so `col` = 0 and `value` = 3222947947. Any idea why `std::stoi(value)` throws the error `std::out_of_range` then?

Comment: 3222947947 -> 3,222,947,947. Over 3 billion. Your standard 32 bit `int` is only valid up to about 2.2 billion. So I'd believe it if the program says the value is out of range. If the value is valid in your input set you'll need to use a larger (`long long` and `std::stoll`) or unsigned data type (`unsigned int` and `std::stoul`) if negative numbers are not in the valid input set.

Comment: what's the command to tranform into uint please?

Comment: Look at [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: There is one really important rule of thumb : Never trust your input.  And learn to handle errors.

Comment: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) and make customer.id `unit64_t` and not `unsigned int` or `int` or perhaps use `std::string` instead since you generally don't do math on a customer id.

Comment: *what's the command to tranform into uint please?* -- C++ does not work by issuing "commands".  You need to declare the appropriate data type, and then call the appropriate function.

Comment: Totally unrelated: A proposed edit wanted to add [the tag `stoi`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stoi). I removed the tag while approving the edit and would like a quick, informal poll on whether or not the tag should be allowed to live.

Comment: @user4581301 I was about to add the tag back but then I saw it has only 18 questions, no tag info. Doesnt look very useful

Comment: Unless you want to also create tags for all the other Standard Library functions, I see no reason to use it or even keep it around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3222947947 -> 3,222,947,947. Over 3 billion.

The [currently-standard 32 bit `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Properties) is only valid up to about 2.2 billion. So I'd believe it if the program says the value is out of range.

If 3222947947  is valid in your input set you'll need to use a larger integer (`long long` or [`int64_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) and convert with [`std::stoll`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)) or unsigned integer (`unsigned int` or `uint32_t` and convert with [`std::stoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul)) if negative numbers are not in the valid input set for `customer.id`.

Answer (score -1):

**C++ stoi throws out_of_range while converting int**

**Mistake:** It reports that you tried to access elements out of bound means out_of_range.

**Correction:** it reports that you tried to convert from higher ranged value to lower ranged value(here in this case integer type).

It (eg. Out of Range error: vector::_M_range_check) may happen any member functions which are accessed by bound-checked member functions like std::bitset, std::basic_string, std::vector, etc.

I think you should change the type of customer.id from int to uint_64 and then cast your value to unit64_t using [boost::lexical_cast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm)

Example:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

struct Customer
{
    uint64_t id = 0;
}customer;

int main()
{
    // You can use either uint_t or uint64_t 
    // depends on the max size of customer.id  
    customer.id = boost::lexical_cast<uint64_t>("3222947947"); 
}
```

If you find above explanation is helpful to you, feel free to comment.

Comment: "It reports that you tried to access elements out of bound means out_of_range. It may happen any member functions which are accessed by bound-checked member functions like std::bitset, std::basic_string, std::vector, etc." - Ehh, *no*. That's not all that `std::out_of_range` can mean. It can also mean (as in this case) that a numerical value is *out of range* of what a given type can hold/represent.

Comment: @JesperJuhl you are right as in this case that a numerical value is out of range. And that's implicitly meaning in this case also. 

example:
    ` std::vector<int>  v(10);`
     ` v[20] = 20; //  Error : Out of Range error: vector::_M_range_check `